# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber objectAtIndex:]

Tags: iphone

Hi I am getting this exception during execution of application.

I have one service through that I want to insert device information to the sever. For this I have taken NSDictionary and I keep the value with following datatype like NSString, and one Long value. 
once I try to insert the data it give the following error msg.

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber objectAtIndex:]

Please help me on that thanks in Advance.

Comment: Pls share some code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to insert a C type in the dictionary. NSDictionaries can only contain objects (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key <-- the value must be an object

To insert the long value as an object, you can make a NSNumber *n = [NSNumber numberWithLong:longValue];
When you need to read it back, you can have [n longValue].

Comment: I am inserting like this. U_ID=1234; UILabel *UID; UID.Text=[NSNumber numberwithLong U_ID]; After that I am passing like that dict=[NSDictionary              dictionaryWithObjects:@[U_ID.text] forKeys:@[@"DeviceName"];

Comment: @[U_ID.text] is an array with one string element. Try using dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:U_ID.text forKey:@"DeviceName"];